# Symfony 2 projects extremely slow under osx yosemite

Tags: php, macos, performance, symfony, io

I recently moved from Lenovo x230 with Ubuntu 14.10 linux to Macbook Pro w OSX Yosemite

and after i configured everything the way it was, i am experiencing extremely poor performance in my Symfony 2 projects, page takes like 5-10 times longer to load.

As far as i can tell there is some I/O problem and PHP has really slow access to files compared to linux, even tho ssd hdd should be a ot faster then the on i had in my old lenovo.

---

**Solution: Disable the FireVault feature in osx, it has very poor performance while working with thousands of small files.**

Comment: Move back to `Ubuntu`!! :). Do you have the same `PHP`/`apache` versions on both ?

Comment: Maybe you configured xdebug not so optimal?

Comment: Yes, i tried with same versions as far as i am able to track this issue, it seems like there is some problem with high amounts of files per process in osx.

Comment: i also tried to disable xdebug and it did not help.

Comment: Finally solved this, problem was in OSX FireVault feature. It has extremely low performance when working with thousands of small files.

Comment: @JJWorren post the solution as an answer, and reedit your question & title to remove the solution from it, so we'll know your question has an answer.